# Haskell ad hoc polymorphism

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, overloading, typeclass

I'm trying to get my head around ad-hoc polymorphism in haskell, that is having the same function provide different behaviour for different argument types.

But while the following test code compiles

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class MyClass a b where
    foo :: a -> b

instance MyClass Bool Int where
    foo True = 0
    foo False = 1

instance MyClass Double Double where
    foo x = -x
```

if I try to call it using something like

```
foo True
```

ghci yells at me:

```
No instance for (MyClass Bool b0) arising from a use of `foo'
The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there is a potential instance available:
  instance MyClass Bool Int -- Defined at test.hs:6:10
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (MyClass Bool b0)
In the expression: foo True
In an equation for `it': it = foo True
```

However, if I specify the return type, it works:

```
foo True :: Int -- gives 0
```

Why is this needed? The parameter type of Bool should be enough to resolve the ambiguity.

Also: Is this the "best" way to achieve similar behaviour? (without renaming the functions to `fooBool` and `fooDouble`)

Comment: to be honest: I would not start with `MultiParamTypeClasses` but in your case you might want to have a look at [`Functional dependencies`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) too ;) (in case it's not clear - follow the link - the problem is nicely explained there - including a possible solution - said extenstion)

Comment: For this task I would use [type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families) rather than functional dependencies.

Comment: @user3237465 add it as an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the overloading is determined by *all* of the types in the class—including ones that only appear as return types. You could have instances for both `MyClass Bool Int` and `MyClass Bool String`, and it would be able to disambiguate based on what type is expected.

One of the core design tradeoffs with Haskell typeclasses is the "open world assumption". Haskell type instances are implicitly global: a specific type (or sequence of types, in this case) can only have *one* instance in the whole program, which is implicitly exported to all the modules using that type.

This makes it really easy to get new instances of some class without realizing it, so the Haskell typechecker assumes that instances *could* possibly exist for any valid combination of types. In your case, this means that while `MyClass Bool Int` is the only instance using `Bool`, it's still ambiguous with other possible `MyClass Bool b` instances.

Once you add an annotation for the type of the whole expression, it stops being ambiguous because both `a` and `b` are fixed.

To get the behavior you expect, you can use [`FunctionalDependencies`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#functional-dependencies). These allow you to specify that there is only *one* possible `b` for any given `a`, which will let GHC infer the type correctly. It would look something like this:

```
class MyClass a b | a -> b where
```

Of course, this does intentionally throw out some flexibility: now you can't have instances for both `MyClass Bool Int` and `MyClass Bool String`.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up some things for me. However even with FunctionalDependencies, the call `foo 1.73` will fail. Can you explain this too?

Comment: if will fail because `1.73` by itself is not `Double` but a more generic `Fractional` - so you have to do `foo (1.73 :: Double)` or modify your `foo` instance for `Fractional a`

Comment: @wonce: The problem here is that `1.73` is polymorphic itself: it can be any `Fractional` type like `Float`, `Double` or `Rational`. So, again, there's possible ambiguity on which instance to use.

Answer (score 7):

**Tikhon Jelvis** elaborated the problem and proposed to use functional dependencies, but there is an alternative: [type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families). Your code becomes

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class MyClass a where
    type R a
    foo :: a -> R a

instance MyClass Bool where
    type R Bool = Int
    foo True  = 0
    foo False = 1

instance MyClass Double where
    type R Double = Double
    foo x = -x
```

We use [associated type synonyms](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/assoc-types/at-syns.pdf) here. I like these explicit type level functions, but if you don't, it's OK to use fundeps, because [differences](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies_vs._type_families) are rather subtle.