# How to overload a function for multiplying [Double] in Haskell (ad-hoc polymorphism)?

Tags: haskell, overloading

The way to have ad-hoc polymorphism (function overloading) in Haskell is through type classes (see answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177019/why-has-haskell-troubles-resolving-overloaded-operators), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039135/haskell-ad-hoc-polymorphism) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944756/best-way-to-implement-ad-hoc-polymorphism-in-haskell) question, among others).

But I'm struggling to define an overloaded `mult` (product) function for the following cases:

```
mult: [Double] -> Double -> [Double]
mult: Double -> [Double] -> [Double]
mult: [Double] -> [Double] -> [Double]
```

Thanks

(At least, case 1 `[Double]*Double` and case 3 `[Double]*[Double]` would be necessary).

Comment: Why do you want this anyway? Just because [Matlab allows multiplying anything you throw at it doesn't mean this is a good idea](http://www.parallelnetz.de/ScriptingHater.html). Check out [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) for properly dealing with multidimensional-multiplications. Alternatively, if you don't care so much for mathematical elegance, you can use [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) (which is in fact a lot like Matlab/Octave in Haskell), or [linear](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for your link. Do you mean it is not a good idea  this kind of polymorphism (Not only matlab allows it)? Is it a bad idea "in general" or in Haskell?

Comment: Well, I think it's a bad idea in general, and really unnecessary in Haskell because you can just write `map (*x) ys` or `zipWith (*) xs ys` to make you intent explicit. This of course doesn't work for polymorphic code that's supposed to handle both scalars and vectors – however, writing such code to just deal with scalars or lists of any length is rather asking for trouble. It's awkward to specify which list needs to have a length matching which other list and what length the result will be etc.. This is where `vector-space` or `linear` shine, because they check dimensions at compile time.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it this way. Certainly not very nice.

I think anyone should consider the comments and critics by leftaroundaobut to the question, that I quote below for convenience and relevance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Multipliable ta tb tc | ta tb -> tc where
      mul :: ta -> tb -> tc

instance Multipliable [Double] Double [Double] where
          mul p k = map (*k) p --mul p k = map (\a -> k * a) p

instance Multipliable Double [Double] [Double] where
          mul k p = map (*k) p --mul p k = map (\a -> k * a) p

instance Multipliable [Double] [Double] [Double] where
         mul p q = p  -- dummy implementation


r = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  :: [Double]


r1 = (mul :: [Double] -> Double -> [Double]) r 2.0 

r2 = (mul :: Double -> [Double] -> [Double]) 2.0 r

r3 = (mul :: [Double] -> [Double] -> [Double]) r1 r2


main = do
     print r1
     print r2
     print r3
```

> Why do you want this anyway? Just because Matlab allows multiplying
>   anything you throw at it doesn't mean this is a good idea. Check out
>   vector-space for properly dealing with
>   multidimensional-multiplications. Alternatively, if you don't care so
>   much for mathematical elegance, you can use hmatrix (which is in fact
>   a lot like Matlab/Octave in Haskell), or linear.
>
> I think it's a bad idea in general, and really unnecessary in Haskell because you can just write `map (*x) ys` or `zipWith (*) xs ys`
>   to make you intent explicit. This of course doesn't work for
>   polymorphic code that's supposed to handle both scalars and vectors –
>   however, writing such code to just deal with scalars or lists of any
>   length is rather asking for trouble. It's awkward to specify which
>   list needs to have a length matching which other list and what length
>   the result will be etc.. This is where vector-space or linear shine,
>   because they check dimensions at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

As always, statements like "I'm trying (with no success) this" are not quite as useful as you would like: it's good that you included your code, but if you are getting an error message from the compiler, *tell us* what it is! They're very instructive, and are printed for a reason.

I just tried what you wrote, and this is in fact the error message you are (probably) getting:

```
*Multiplication> mul 1 [2]

Non type-variable argument
  in the constraint: Multipliable ta [t] tc
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
  it :: forall ta tc t. (Num ta, Num t, Multipliable ta [t] tc) => tc
```

Now, you could try just turning on FlexibleContexts, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. But, as is often the case when the compiler is telling you it's having trouble inferring types, you should try adding some explicit types and see if that helps:

```
*Multiplication> mul (1::Double) [2 :: Double]
[2.0]
```

Basically, the compiler can't be sure which overload of `mul` you want: `1` and `2` are polymorphic and could be any numeric type, and while there is only one suitable overload for `mul` *now*, the compiler doesn't make such an inference unless it can prove no other overload could ever exist in this context. Fully specifying the argument types is enough to resolve the problem.

An alternative approach to this particular problem is to use a typeclass for each argument, to convert it into the canonical type `[Double]`, rather than a typeclass for the arguments as a whole. This is a more specific solution than general ad hoc polymorphism, and not all problems will fit, but for something like treating a single number like a list of numbers it should be fine:

```
module Multiplication where
import Control.Monad (liftM2)

class AsDoubles a where
  doubles :: a -> [Double]

instance AsDoubles Double where
  doubles = return

instance AsDoubles [Double] where
  doubles = id

mult :: (AsDoubles a, AsDoubles b) => a -> b -> [Double]
mult x y = liftM2 (*) (doubles x) (doubles y)

*Multiplication> mult [(1 :: Double)..5] [(1 :: Double)..3]
[1.0,2.0,3.0,      -- whitespace added for readability
 2.0,4.0,6.0,
 3.0,6.0,9.0,
 4.0,8.0,12.0,
 5.0,10.0,15.0]
```

Comment: I think you got wrong that I want somebody to correct "my code". I just want the general solution (if any) to the question. Forget the code. My note was only to show that I'm not just waiting for anyone do the job. Thanks for your answer. Gonna try it.